# I need to know the names of the angels and their actions in Hinduism

Tags: puranas

I have a research and I need to know all the names of angels in different religions and their actions, and since I am an Arab, my sources are not enough and I need the names of angels in Hinduism

Comment: Angels are called Pari in Hinduism. The well known scriptures like Puranas etc don't mention their names. But some not so well known Tantras (which are dealing with Pari Sadhana) mention some names of Pari-s.

Comment: There are no angels as you understand them in Hinduism.